# Add QuickType (Predictive) to custom keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard in iOS 8. I saw in the Keyboard' Apple that have function Quick type (Predictive : On) to quick input text 
Is there any ways to add this function to my keyboard ?
Please help me !
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no way to do this as of iOS8 BETA 5. Not sure why this got down votes and close votes...

Comment: Thank so much for your comment. But I just searched that have UILexicon can give us a dictionary to get correct word. But I dont know how to use it.
Other question ! How can I debug when I run app custom keyboard in the KeyboardViewController : UIInputViewController Class ?
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILexicon_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILexicon/entries

Comment: @PaulNguyen That is a completely different thing... you were asking about `quick type`. `Quick Type` is an Apple feature which shows suggested words above the keyboard and you can tap on the ones you want. You are just talking about auto correct at the moment.

Comment: Hi Albert Renshaw
I am asking and talking about quick type function.May be I use "a dictionary to get correct word" not match with I want, Sorry about that.
I researched in the Apple document, that said we should use UILexicon. But NSLog does not WORK in the KeyboardViewController : UIInputViewController Class,
Can you help me to show NSLog in the Xcode 6 beta 5 ?

Comment: You would have to program your own from scratch... UILexicon just shows words specific to that device, like last names in the user's contacts book... it is not a dictionary of all correct words, it also is not a function that returns a list of words that are similar to the word you typed or predictive of the word you are typing, this will all have to be a custom function :) I've been working on my auto correct algorithm to be as accurate as Apple's default one for two weeks now, just finished last night. I also can't get NSLog to work /: I just use simulator and it works, but not on device.

Comment: Thanks  Albert Renshaw